# What tools or techniques are available to "datamine" my mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, code-statistics

We have a 2,000,000 lines of code application in Mercurial.  Obviously there is a lot of valuable information inside this repository.

Are there any tools or techniques to dig out some of that information?

For instance, over the history of the project, what five files have seen the most changes?  What five files are the most different from what they were one year ago?  Any particular lines of code seen a lot of churn?

I'm interested in that sort of thing and more.

Is there a way to extract this kind of information from our repository?

Comment: This isn't really [tag:data-mining]. You are asking for trivial, straight-forward statistics, as provided by StatSVN/StatCVS for other version control systems. Plus, this is not a programming question.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. So how do I get these trivial statistics out of mercurial?

Comment: Nick, did you find anything useful without having to roll-your-own?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know of any tools specifically made for doing this, but Mercurial's log templates are very powerful for getting data out of the system.  I've done a bit of this sort of analysis in the past, and my approach was:

1. Use `hg log` to dump commits to some convenient format (xml in my case)
2. Write a script to import the xml into something queryable (database, or just work from the XML directly if it's not too big)

Here's an example `hg log` command to get you going:

mystyle.txt: (template)

```
changeset = '<changeset>\n<user>{author|user}</user>\n<date>{date|rfc3339date|escape}</date>\n<files>\n{file_mods}{file_adds}{file_dels}</files>\n<rev>{node}</rev>\n<desc>{desc|strip|escape}</desc>\n<branch>{branches}</branch><diffstat>{diffstat}</diffstat></changeset>\n\n'
file_mod = '<file action="modified">{file_mod|escape}</file>\n'
file_add = '<file action="added">{file_add|escape}</file>\n'
file_del = '<file action="deleted">{file_del|escape}</file>\n'
```

Example invocation using template and date range:

```
hg --repository /path/to/repo log -d "2012-01-01 to 2012-06-01" --no-merges --style mystyle.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the built-in [hg churn](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChurnExtension) extension. One thing I like to use it for, for example, is to see a monthly bar graph of commits like this:

```
> hg churn -csf '%Y-%m'

2014-02     65 *************************************
2014-03     22 *************
2014-04     52 ******************************
2014-05     67 ***************************************
2014-06     31 ******************
2014-07     29 *****************
2014-08     29 *****************
2014-09     61 ***********************************
2014-10     36 *********************
2014-11     23 *************
2014-12     32 ******************
2015-01     60 ***********************************
2015-02     20 ************
```

(might want to set up aliases if you find you're using the command often enough)